# Why Bitmap size is bigger in memory than on disk in Android?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, size, heap-memory

I have a 2448x3264 image on my SD card that consumes 1,667,072 bytes but when I load it as a Bitmap and calculate its size using `getRowBytes()*getHeight()` I end up with 15,980,544 bytes.

Why does this happen and how can I calculate the actual size of the file?

Comment: What is the format of this image?

Comment: format is jpeg. I think Devunwired answered it

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That is because the image is compressed when it is on disk (stored in a JPG, PNG, or similar format).  Once you load the image into memory, it is no longer compressed and takes up as much memory as is necessary for all the pixels (typically width * height * 4 for RGBA_8888, or width * height * 2 for RGB_565).

Comment: ok, I understand now. Just to confirm if I compress the bitmap using bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) to a FileOutputStream and read the bitmap again even then it will give the large size. Right?

Comment: Correct, a compressed image is only a file storage format.  In order to actually work with the data, it has to be inflated back into a full Bitmap in memory.

Comment: I have a 1024*600 img being read into mem on Android. My calcs say 1024*600*4 = ~3 MB whereas DDMS is telling me its 4.2 MB in mem, any idea what causes the extra overhead?