# Android image heap error

Tags: android, image, background-image

My app is running on my android phone (Motorola Milestone).

I have 2 XML files, Splash and MainActivity and just a ListActivity Menu file for redirecting for future.

The process is: App debug -> Splash -> (just view for 4 seconds) -> redirect to Menu -> on select, (CRASH) redirect to MainActivity

In Splash.xml and MainActivity.xml I have background images and here is where the problem occurs. I have 4 images I put for testing:

```
1. fon.jpg -> 112KB -> 1000x600
2. rockguitar.jpg -> 92KB -> 1280 x 1024
3. intro_low.jpg -> 80KB -> 850 x 1100
4. start_low.jpg -> 56KB -> 850 x 1100
```

I tried various combinations of those files to check if maybe my code was wrong, but everything works correctly and images show, except when I use 3. and 4. together, no matter in which XML it will throw an error with:

```
16830000-byte external allocation too large for this process. VM won't let us allocate 16830000 bytes.
```

But it works in any other combination (1. and 4., 3. and 2. etc.)
Those last two images I made in Photoshop, if that is of any help. I through it was the sizing issue, so I made them smaller, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Edit: It crashes AT THE SAME SPOT every time, where (CRASH) is in the small diagram.

EDIT SECOND PART:

I want to add the background to the whole window, so when I get to the it, it has those 4 list options and one background at the bottom. This is all the code I have. Or how can I connect an XML file and just put all the styling in it? Because I use setContent(R.layout.my_layout), it throws an error.

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "MainActivity", "ex1", "ex2", "ex3" };

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String strClass = classes[position];
        Class ourClass;
        try {
            ourClass = Class.forName("rock.school.rzn.rockquiz." + strClass);
            Intent outIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
            startActivity(outIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, classes));
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start_low, options); 

        BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        listView.setPadding(0, 150, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the crash log says your images are just too big. The size of the image on the disk is not the same as the size of the image in memory, because on disk the image is compressed. The in memory size has to do with the image's width and height, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461061/why-bitmap-size-is-bigger-in-memory-than-on-disk-in-android) similar question.

So if we assume RGBA_8888, your images' sizes in memory should be something like :

```
1. 1.90 MB
2. 4.76 MB
3. 2.86 MB
4. 2.86 MB
```

If your images don't need the alpha channel (ie they are not transparent) you can load them using RGBA_555:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_icon, options); 

BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
View yourview = findViewById(R.id.your_id);
yourview.setBackground(drawable);
```

You can do that in your Activity's `onCreate` method. Then use `findViewById()` to get hold of the view (ie an ImageView) and set the bitmap.

Update 2:

Please try this. In your res/layout folder create an my_layout.xml file and paste the following :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list_background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then edit your Activity's onCreate method like the one below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, classes));

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start_low, options); 

    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    View background = findViewById(R.id.list_background);
    background.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); 
}
```

Comment: Follow up: but why the other two images work? They are even bigger in compressed state.

Comment: Are those images transparent? If not you could load them with RGB_565 which would reduce the needed memory.

Comment: With those calculations, it is likely that 1. and 2. would crash. And no, all images are non-transparent. And how would I do it inside XML with the backgroud? Or would I set the background inside the .java?

Comment: I'm having troubles setting the bitmap as the background. Where do I do it?

Comment: All I have a ListActivity java class.
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, classes));
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

This is all I have in the onCreate.

I don't have layouts or anything. What ID do I use?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code of your activity? Could you also note where are you trying to apply the background (which views)?

Comment: Change setBackgroundDrawable to setBackground. But apart from that, you should see a background on your listview.

Comment: setBackground is not a defined function. I changed that myself from your code.

Comment: Yes you are right setBackground was introduced in SDK 16, it doesn't matter. Please see if my updated answer can help you.

Comment: That does help quite a bit, but I still don't know how to change the text inside. All of that was done with my inline. I will give you the accepted answer, because you solved the issues :)